# How do I stop a module from overriding Python's standard library modules?

Tags: python

Here's a specific example: In my Python code, I have a logging folder that is a Python code module:

```
.
|-- logging
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- my_code.py
```

When I run `python -m venv` in that directory, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 146, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\venv\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'
```

The reason that happens appears to be that venv is importing my logging folder instead of [Python's logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). According to [this article](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html):

> Unlike built-in modules which are first in the search path, the rest
> of the modules in Python’s standard library (not built-ins) come after
> the directory of the current script. This leads to confusing behavior:
> it is possible to “replace” some but not all modules in Python’s
> standard library. For example, on my computer (Windows 10, Python
> 3.6), the math module is a built-in module, whereas the random module is not. Thus, import math in start.py will import the math module from
> the standard library, NOT my own math.py file in the same directory.
> However, import random in start.py will import my random.py file, NOT
> the random module from the standard library.

Probably the easiest solution is to just switch to a temporary other directory, but is there any other way I can run a module included in Python, without worrying that something in my code will overwrite part of it?

Comment: I don't really understand the quote from the linked article. Importing both `math` or `random` should always set priority to local files over bulit-ins. And random **is a bulitin module**, despite what it says

Comment: Yes, the easiest solution is to rename your own folder not to conflict with built-in modules

Comment: Perhaps the article author read through `sys.builtin_module_names` and missed `_random`? In any case, logging is definitely not a built-in module, and definitely prioritizes local files over built-ins. And according to [Python's own docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), at least in 3.10.2, built-in modules should take precedence over `sys.path`.

Comment: What do you mean? [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) is definitely built-in...

Comment: Also, you can create a venv in any directory, so I suspect you just found an edge-case that can be resolved by moving to any other directory

Comment: Yes... `logging` is part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html)

Comment: We need to distinguish between built-in as in "included with an installation of Python," or "compiled into this Python interpreter." `sys.builtin_module_names` on my local machine doesn't include `logging`. A module can be in the standard library without being compiled into Python.

Comment: `sys.builtin_module_names` is not the source of truth for what is part of the standard library. Assuming you have installed Python from your OS's package manager, `logging` is definitely there, and there isn't a way to specify "import explicitly from my standard library" or not. Especially not when running external tooling.

Comment: @OneCricketeer: You're mixing up concepts here. "Built-in module" in this context means a C module compiled directly into the Python interpreter. It has nothing to do with whether something is or isn't part of the standard library, and Chris never claimed it did.

Comment: (As an aside, `random` is not built-in. `_random`, a C helper module for `random`, is built-in on a Windows build of Python, but I believe this is only the case on Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

> any way I can run a module included in Python, without worrying that something in my code will overwrite part of it

You could try exporting `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, but I think the local directory will always be first, as [the "Module Search Path" link you provided](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) says, "The directory containing the input script" will always be searched first, then `PYTHONPATH` is second.

> Probably the easiest solution is to just switch to a temporary other directory

Correct.

```
$ (cd /tmp; python3 -m venv /path/to/your-venv)
```

> `sys.builtin_module_names` on my local machine doesn't include logging

It's not there on mine, either, and I wouldn't trust that article that suggests it should include everything from the standard library. Did you try `import logging` from some other folder?

Or how about something like this

```
$ python3 -c 'help("modules")' 2>/dev/null | grep logging
_contextvars        binhex              logging             string
```